# SystemD not running an ExecStartPre until I reload and restart the service

Tags: systemd

I am overriding the `/usr/lib/systemd/system/docker.service` start-up script to extend it with an environment file. I have defined my configuration file at `/etc/systemd/system/docker.service.d/docker.conf` like so:

```
test -d /etc/systemd/system/docker.service.d || \
    mkdir /etc/systemd/system/docker.service.d

cat > /etc/systemd/system/docker.service.d/docker.conf <<EOF
[Service]
EnvironmentFile=/etc/sysconfig/docker
ExecStartPre=-/usr/local/sbin/generate-docker-config
ExecStart=
ExecStart=/usr/bin/docker daemon -H fd:// --dns=\${LOCAL_IPV4}
EOF

systemctl daemon-reload
```

I'm running the above script as a [Packer](https://packer.io) build step for an AMI.

When I launch my AMI, I see the following status output about the Docker service from SystemD:

```
● docker.service - Docker Application Container Engine
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/docker.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
  Drop-In: /etc/systemd/system/docker.service.d
           └─docker.conf
   Active: active (running) since Mon 2016-03-28 21:16:11 UTC; 6min ago
     Docs: https://docs.docker.com
 Main PID: 858 (docker)
   CGroup: /system.slice/docker.service
           ├─ 858 /usr/bin/docker daemon -H fd:// --dns=10.224.4.178 --log-driver=syslog --log-opt tag={{.ImageName}}
```

It hasn't run my `ExecStartPre`, as seen in the output. If I do the following, I *do* see that it has now run the startup script:

```
# systemctl daemon-reload && systemctl restart docker.service && \
    systemctl status docker.service
● docker.service - Docker Application Container Engine
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/docker.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
  Drop-In: /etc/systemd/system/docker.service.d
           └─docker.conf
   Active: active (running) since Mon 2016-03-28 22:05:24 UTC; 24ms ago
     Docs: https://docs.docker.com
  Process: 1873 ExecStartPre=/usr/local/sbin/generate-docker-config (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 1876 (docker)
   CGroup: /system.slice/docker.service
           └─1876 /usr/bin/docker daemon -H fd:// --dns=10.224.4.178 --log-driver=syslog --log-opt tag={{.ImageName}}
```

Notice how it now has the `ExecStartPre` in the status output?

Is there a command I should be running in my Packer build in addition to `daemon-reload` to cause SystemD to load and run the new service configuration file and `ExecStartPre` script? Should I just `restart` the service in the Packer build, or is there a better, more tailored solution to the problem?

NOTE: My `ExecStartPre` script needs the network available to `curl` for EC2 instance tags. The Docker service file does specify `After=network.target docker.socket` so I'm assuming it will run after networking has started.

Comment: After=docker.service should work as well since docker requires network.target
But, I think a key issue here is that ExecStartPre does not seem to be run at all if service <name> restart is invoked instead of service <name> stop && service <name> start

Answer (score 1):

Well, this is the expected behavior. If you intend to restart the docker service just after overriding the docker unit file, you are supposed to invoke `systemctl restart docker.service` after `systemctl daemon-reload` in the script. If you also wants to restart docket only if it is already running, invoke `systemctl try-restart docker.service` instead.

The purpose of `systemctl daemon-reload` commands is to tell `systemd` daemon to reload all its configuration, reload units files and regenerate the service dependency tree. However, it doesn't affect any other service in the system, even though unit files are changed on disk.

Comment: The unexpected part of the behavior is that when I _restart_ the system, it doesn't load in the `ExecStartPre`. The Packer EC2 instance is shut down, and then the next time it is launched is as an AMI for a new EC2 instance, and the problem is that during _this_ phase, it doesn't call the script.

Comment: Then, I am afraid I couldn't help you with the issue. I know how to manage services with `systemd`, but I don't know how to deal with Amazon compute clouds. The only possible cause I figure is that the script doesn't restart `docker.service` after overriding its unit file and it should do.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the network is 'online' after `network.service` isn't 100% reliable.  That's why there's a `network-online.target`.

If you're relying on curl and want to be absolutely sure the network is up before the service starts, DNS works, etc. then adding this to your `docker.conf` might help ...

```
[Unit]
After=network-online.target
```

... and since you're doing all this post boot, for the new `ExecStartPre` to work, then you should add either `systemctl daemon-reload && systemctl restart docker.service` or `systemctl stop docker.service && systemctl daemon-reload && systemctl start docker.service` in your Packer build script.  The latter is most reliable.

Stopping a service before it's modified and `daemon-reload` is done will ensure the entire unit is reloaded as specified.  I can see in the third bit of output you've provided that the `ExecStart` for `docker.service` does *not* contain the arguments you've specified in the Packer build script.  That's because of the `systemctl restart docker.service` (versus stop, daemon-reload, & start).